# why is java.lang.StackOverflowError given in the computing of pi using the Taylor series expansion?

Tags: java, math, stack-overflow, pi

As a school project I am trying to calculate the value of pi using the taylor expansion of `arctan(x)`, as `arctan(1) = π/4`. I made this program to calculate the value of pi but I need very large values of count to calculate it and whenever I put the limit to value of more than **10000**, say **20000** i get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError   
at extended_essay.Talyor_pi_arctan.calculate(Talyor_pi_arctan.java:18) 

The line "at extended_essay.Talyor_pi_arctan.calculate(Talyor_pi_arctan.java:18)"
```

is repeated a multiple times.

I do not want to handle the exception as that would increase the time taken. 
Please tell me why this is happening and what other possible solutions could i use?

**EXTRA INFORMATION:**

```
the taylor expansion of arctan(x) is

Summation of (((-1)^n) / 2n+1) * ((x)^(2n+1))
```

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
public class Talyor_pi_arctan {
    static double count = 0, val = 0, pi = 0, limit = 10000;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        calculate();
        pi *= 4;
        System.out.println("Value of pi calculated: " +pi);
        System.out.println("Actual value of pi :   " +Math.PI);
    }
    public static void calculate(){
        if(count >= limit){
            return;
        }
        val = (Math.pow(-1d, count) / ((2 * count) + 1)) * Math.pow(1, ((2*count)+1));
        pi = pi + val;
        ++count;
        calculate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unnecessary recursion producing many stack frames, leading to stack overflow, just turn it into a loop

Comment: There is a recursion in your code , it may lead to stackoverflow exception

Comment: Note that the error of this approximation is `1/(2n+1)` for a sum with `n` terms. Look up "Machin-like formulas" for faster converging combinations of the arcus tangent formula.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive calls of `calculate()` cause StackOverflowError.

1. You can calculate in a loop, not in recursion.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < termsNumber; i++) {
       result += f(i)
   }
   ```
2. You can set limit not to 10000 according to accuracy you really need.
3. `Math.pow(-1d, count)` is a bad way of calculation, use

   ```
   count % 2 == 0 ? 1d : -1d
   ```
4. `Math.pow(1, ((2*count)+1) == 1`